# Add properties to django models at runtime?

Tags: python, django

Specifically, I have django model objects I'd like to add properties to at runtime. It'd be great if this would work on any python class outside of Django.

I have the following models

models.py

```
class person(models.Model):
    # ...
    firstname=models.TextField(max_length=100)
    lastname=models.TextField(max_length=100)
    type=models.TextField(max_length=100)
    address = models.ForeignKey(address, null=True)

class event(models.Model):
    date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True )
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)     
    attendees = models.ManyToManyField(person)

def main():
    p = person()
    p.fisrtsname="Firsty"
    p.lastname="Lasty"
    p.addnewproperty(newtemporaryproperty)
    p.newtemporaryproperty="This is a new temporary property"
```

when i use

```
person.newtemporaryproperty=property("")
```

I get a "Can't set attribute error" when trying to add a value to it.
I may be using it wrong.

EDIT

What i want to do is see if each person in a model has attended an event. and if they have, put a checkbox by their name. Here are the additional related files

tables.py

```
class AttendeesTable(tables.Table):
    firstname = tables.Column()
    lastname = tables.Column()
    here = tables.TemplateColumn('<input id="attendee_{{ record.pk }}" {{ 
record.here }} type="checkbox" />',
                             verbose_name="Here?")

    class Meta:
        attrs = {'id': 'attendancetable', 'width': '100%', 'class': 'table 
table-hover'}
        template = 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html'
        row_attrs = {
            'id': lambda record: str(record.pk),

        }
```

views.py

```
def markattendancepage(request):
    person.here = ""
    people= person.objects.all()
    groups = group.objects.all()
    eventid= 1 #set to 1 for testing
    table=None
    for p in people:

        if event.objects.filter(id=eventid, attendees__pk=p.id).exists():

            p.here = "checked"
        else:
            p.here = ""

        table = app.tables.AttendeesTable(people)


    RequestConfig(request, paginate=False).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'app/user/attendancechecker.html', {'attendeetable':table})

    pass
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? This is almost certainly a poor idea with Django model instances.

Comment: At any rate, for *property*, you provide at least a getter for the property. If you want something to happen when you assign a new value to the property, you need to also provide a setter. If you just want a regular *attribute* just do `obj.attr = 'value'`

Comment: I'm performing calculations to see if a person in a list of people falls into a specific category. if they do, I want to set a new property, that doesn't have any reason to be in the database, to the value "checked", if they dont, i want to set that value to "" so that way, when I pass it to the django-tables2 class, it will know that the record needs a checked checkbox in it. @sytech

Comment: What you might want to do then is make a method to query this on the model manager. Also, you can create a python property on a django model class and it will have no affect on the DB. (Of course, this means you cannot query by such a property, either!) -- For example, you can have a property like `is_something` so each object will have that property and it can be used in views, templates, etc.

Comment: the first comment you provided worked great. although, the benchmark is a little slow. I'm not sure if there's a good, ORM way to do this. but basically. I'm checking to see if every one of my person objects attended an event, if they did, put a check by there name, if not..dont. right now I'm looping through every person object and running "if event.objects.filter(id=eventid,attendees__pk=p.id).exists(): p.here="checked" if there's a better, more pythonic way to do that, please do let me know. thanks. I can update the questino to reflect that. @sytech

Comment: If you can provide your complete models, I'll update my answer with a query you can use for the same effect.

Comment: I updated the question. @sytech

Comment: If your goal is to see the atendees of an event... You already have that defined on your event model. Instead of querying all the people and checking if they're in the event..... simply lookup the event instance and access its `attendees` field. IE `evnt = event.objects.get(pk=eventid); table = AttendeesTable(evnt.attendees)`

Comment: i also want all the people that weren't at the event, just without the check. I think what you said in your answer about running the "is_in_catagory" function from the template will work. You've helped so much. Thank you.

Comment: Then you can do `did_not_attend = people.objects.exclude(id__in=evnt.attendees)` But for a template table, the property probably makes the most sense, since it's a row-level thing. You could also try *annotating* your query with this as a virtual field for the same effect, but not sure how the performance would be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because django model instances often get reloaded behind the scenes, you probably don't want to set attributes at runtime, because they can easily get lost. Instead, what you might want to do is have a property (or a method) in the class definition such as

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @property
    def is_in_category(self):
        # 'calculation' return a boolean
        return True if something else False
```

Then if you have any particular instance of `Person` you can check the `is_in_category` property

```
for person in Person.objects.all():
    if person.is_in_category:
        # do something
```

This also works in templates... for instance if you wanted to make a table of people

```
<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>In category?</th></tr>
{% for person in people %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ person.first_name }}, {{person.last_name}}</td>
      <td>{% if person.is_in_category %}Yes{% else %}No{% endif %}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

However, because properties only exist as Python constructs, you cannot use SQL queries based on this property.

```
# this will not work
people_in_category = Person.objects.filter(is_in_category=False)
```

If you want to perform queries like this, you would need to create a field on the model or a related model or otherwise come up with an SQL expression that is the equivalent of the property.

Edit:

Given your models, you can perform a query that should do the same thing. Your `event` model has an `attendees` field which would be what you're looking for and would be the way to do this since it appears you have the event id in-hand and access to the event model.

```
evnt = event.objects.get(pk=eventid)
evnt.attendees # people who attended the event
did_not_attend = people.objects.exclude(id__in=evnt.attendees)
```

You may want to consider making a method on the model manager that annotates a query for the same effect that the property gives you. For example

```
class PersonManager(models.Manager):
    def for_event(self, evnt):
        attended_event = person.objects.filter(id__in=evnt.attendees)
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        return qs.annotate(attended=Exists(attended_event))
```

Then if you register this manager with your people model you can do

```
for p in person.objects.for_event(evnt):
    if p.attended:
        # they attended the event
```

Comment: @Philip556677 - I updated my answer to include the queryable solutions.